# Why did Vyasa accept Vaishampayana as his student?

Tags: mahabharata

Vaishampayana was the student of Vyasa. Vyasa himself gave him the permission to narrate the Mahabharata to Janamejaya. He was the first narrator of Mahabharata. My question is why did Vyasa allow Vaishampayana to narrate his epic poem and accept him as his first student when he slew a Brahmana in ignorance, polluted by the slaughter, and was put down by the gods?

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a006.htm

> Was not the regenerate Rishi Vaisampayana too, who slew a Brahmana in ignorance, and was polluted by the slaughter of a child, put down by the gods?